# why react dev tools is blocking my main thread

Tags: reactjs, pagespeed

I measured my React application as part of my efforts to make the application faster and to improve the [pagespeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) score.

Unfortunately I saw that there is one script that his size is 3kb and he is blocking the main thread for 2,591 ms and sometimes even more (Screenshot attached).

I clicked on the chunk there and saw that this code is belong to react dev tools (I realized that after I used beatify javascript because it's a minified version there).

This is the measurement that I did:

https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-stage-nectarsleep-com-mattress/k5wzto87w0?form_factor=mobile

What can I do in order to reduce this long blocking time?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to do your page speed testing against the production build, not dev.    (Unless you mean the browser plugin "react developer tools" is blocking, in which case disable the plugin before running your perf tests.)

Comment: I did this measurments on stage env which is using the production build (minifications etc.) @DanielBeck

Comment: I can see this react-dev tools code in my production environment measurement also @DanielBeck

Comment: OK, then that must be the browser plugin.  Disable that before running your tests.

Comment: Nope, Unfortunately it's still there even after I turned it off.
I think Pagespeed is simulating a remote device for this tests so It will not help to turn it off on my own machine. Any other idea please? @DanielBeck

Comment: Hm, it looks like that particular piece of code is hosted on assets.residenthome.com, is that part of your site or under your control?  (Pagespeed would not be inserting that). Maybe residenthome are the ones who accidentally left developer tools in their production build?  I can't read the minified code well enough to say.

Comment: Yes it's under our website. We are storing all the chunks for our react application in this domain. @DanielBeck

Comment: Something might be messed up with your server. The script in question does not contain the react devtools header javascript code when it's embedded in your site. But it does exist if you open the script in a new incognito window, like https://assets.residenthome.com/nectar/212788/public/javascripts/85895-nectar.js. Pagespeed might be seeing a different version of your javascript code. Either way, if you have devtools in prod,  you're building your app incorrectly, and should remove it.

Comment: @AndyRay Hi, I succeed to remove the devtools from my production build but still facing long blocking time there. 
This is the unminified version of the chunk that have long blocking time:
https://codesandbox.io/s/chunk-unminified-6qhnl9
I'm not familiar with this code and I don't know what to do in order to solve it right now :/ any ideas?

Comment: I think that code is core to React based on Googling for some of the error strings. I'd guess it's not React/devtools itself blocking the thread, but rather your use of it. I would profile your app's Javascript usage in Chrome and see if there's any obvious huge operation(s) you do. I think you'll need to do more debugging since the amount of work required to dig through a performance flame graph is probably higher than what someone will do for you on SO. You could also disable "mangling" in your prod bundling to retain original method/variable names to help debug the flame graph.